# BCrypt error Illegal arguments: string, object

Tags: node.js, authentication, bcrypt

I am developing a NodeJS and ReactJS based web application in which I am trying to hash the passwords in multiple routes, one for registration and other for changing password.

For this purpose, I am generating the salt outside both routes so they both utilize the same salt like this:

```
const salt = bcrypt.genSalt(10);
```

Now inside the routes, the has is being generated like this:

```
user.password = await bcrypt.hash(newPassword, salt);
```

But when I run this, it gives the following console error:

*Illegal arguments: string, object*

The hashing operation was working fine when I was generating the salt inside the individual routes. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this.

Don't forget to await the genSalt function like so:

```js
const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
```

The error: `Illegal arguments: string, object` tries to explain that one of the arguments passed to the hash function is invalid, since it's type is invalid.

In this case it's the second argument *(salt)* which expects a string/number but receives an object *(the promise object that's returned if you don't `await`)*.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 3):

If it helps anyone out there, I've had the same issue but my `genSalt` code was fine.

My problem was that I had some users whose passwords were uninitialized, so no salt had been generated and it was the `bcrypt.compare` function that was failing because it was trying to compare to `NULL`

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're calling `bcrypt.hash` like this

`await bcrypt.hash(newPassword, 10);`

This means that you're passing the number of rounds, not a salt. If you want to generate the salt outside of the call you can do something like this

`const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);`

And then use it in `bcrypt.hash`.

Comment: No I was actually doing it like this:
`await bcrypt.hash(newPassword, salt);`

Comment: Ok. Then maybe there's a shadowing of variable. Try to change the name from salt to something like saltrandomstringhere and see if that works.

Comment: Actually `const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);` did work for me. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it helped you

Comment: However, there is a problem, since I generated the salt outside of the routes, it generates a new salt every time. Therefore, I cannot compare the old password with the new password. Is there any way I can have the same salt for both routes? Or if I can compare them with the salt.

Comment: Nevermind. I fixed it using Bcrypt compare:
`const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(oldPassword, user.password);`

Answer (score 0):

looking at the docs, i believe the error is caused by the call back function missing in your genSalt().. genSaltSync() works well without the call back..